# Why does'n boost::spirit match foo123 with (+alpha | +alnum) grammar?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-spirit

I have a more complex boost::spirit grammar that doesn't match like I expected.
I was able to break it down to this minimal example: http://ideone.com/oPu2e7 (doesn't compile there, but compiles with VS2010)

Basically this is my grammar:

```
my_grammar() : my_grammar::base_type(start)
{
    start %=
        (+alpha | +alnum)
    ;
}
qi::rule<Iterator, std::string(), ascii::space_type> start;
```

It matches *foobar*, *123foo* but doesn't match *foo123*. Why? I would expect it to match all three.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PEG parsers match greedy, left-to-right. That should be enough to explain.

But lets look at `foo123`: it matches "1 or more `+alpha`, so the first branch is taken. The second branch is not taken, so the numerics `123` remain unparsed.

There's no "inherent" backtracking on the kleen operators. You /can/ employ backtracking if you know e.g. that you need to parse the full input:

```
 (+alpha >> eoi | +alnum >> eoi)
```

Comment: Did you really mean to emphasize by putting a word between to forward slashes?

Comment: Thanks, that matches `foo123` - but as a match result I get `foofoo123` - so the match of `+alpha` and `+alnum` even though I have a `|` between both branches and the first branch doesn't match fully.

Comment: That's a common pitfall with container attributes. You can use `qi::hold[]`

Comment: I found the time to look for background answers for that: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A85371+%5Bboost-spirit%5D+hold